# Managment of JSON objects and JSON arrays

Tags: java, json

I'm new with JSON and my question might be not very hard, but I can not find the way to deal with my purpose.
I'm trying to develop the code so that I can manage some JSON content. In my case the JSON info is:

```
{"posts":[{"id":1a00b,"name":"Michael Thomson","info":"he is crazy"},
{"id":18,"name":"Jason Williams","info":"he is tall"}]}
```

Now, I'd like to get the strings from each JSON object (using Java). That's the code I have developed:

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);           
String jsonResult = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();                      
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonResult.getJSONArray("posts");

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) 
{
     JSONObject childJSONObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
     String id = childJSONObject.getString("id");
     String name = childJSONObject.getString("name");
     String info = childJSONObject.getString("info");
}
```

The error seems to be related with the sentence:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonResult.getJSONArray("posts");
```

> The method getJSONArray(String) is undefined for the type String

Those are the libraries I'm using to deal with

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONArray;
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: It says "The method getJSONArray(String) is undefined for the type String"

Comment: `jsonResult` is of type `String`, but you're treating it like a `JSONObject` or `JSONArray`. Wrap the `jsonResult` in a `JSONObject` and then get its "posts" property, which will be a `JSONArray`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jsonResult is a String. You need to turn it into a JSONObject first.

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
JSONArray jsonArray = obj.getJSONArray("posts");
```